# Function not returning the Value of its Key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm writing a function that constructs a `dictionary` from a given file. The file contains lines of data like: `7576240,Sigrid,Rahn`. The number is an ID, and the rest is a first and second name. my task is to create a `dictionary` with the ID as a `Key` and the the first and last name as a `Value` in a tuple format. 
I have managed to do so, but when i try to do this :

```
students_dict = read_class_from_file('class1.txt')
print(students_dict['7576240'])
```

it returns the:

```
2365568 : ('Josef', 'Krten')
3544826 : ('Bernadene', 'Klimas')
5215521 : ('Florie', 'Starkebaum')
6914206 : ('Minnaminnie', 'Sridhar')
7576240 : ('Sigrid', 'Rahn')
8963113 : ('Sharri', 'Benyon')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <fragment>
builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I think the dictionary is working fine, untill i call a Key to get its Value,can someone help with this?

My code:

```
def read_class_from_file(filename):
    ''' function reads all data in (filename) and returns a dictionary '''
    dictionary = {}
    lines = []
    data = [line.strip() for line in open(filename, 'r')]
    for line in data[1:]:
        lines += [line.split(",")]
    for lina in lines:
        dictionary[lina[0]] = (lina[1], lina[2])
    for key in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
        print("{0} : {1}".format(key, dictionary[key]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your function.
You'll have to add

```
return dictionary
```

to the end of your definition of `read_class_from_file`. Since it doesn't currently return anything, `students_dict` is `None`.

Comment: I've used the `print()` statement instead because i need it in a specific format. e.g: `2365568 : ('Josef', 'Krten')`

Comment: Try returning `dictionary` and see if that doesn't fix your problem. Since you're assigning to `student_dict` the value _returned_ by `read_class_from_file` but not returning anything (for which you must use the keyword `return`), it ends up as being `None`. That's where your error comes from.

Comment: It has indeed. but now what about returning the dictionary in the format: `3544826 : ('Bernadene', 'Klimas')` ?

Comment: You can't return the dictionary in any particular format. You just return a dictionary. Perhaps what you want is to _print_ the dictionary in a particular format. That's what you're doing at the end of your function definition. But there's no such thing as a format for a dictionary. So what you'd want is to return `dictionary` and then do something like `print("{0}: {1}".format('7576240', students_dict['7576240'])`.

Comment: I have tried doing that. it says that the `print()` statement will never be reached. There are two things that i need with the function: to print out the `dictionary` in a certain format, and to return a `value` when the `Key` is called. the second is working fine, but not the first.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should print _after_ the `return` statement. Rather, after you call the function and assign its return value to `students_dict` you _then_ call `print`.